# SSH multiple routers connected via switch

Tags: networking, router, ssh, switch

I want to capture wireless packets with multiple routers using `tcpdump`.
I can capture wireless packets with just one router but I want to capture with multiple routers simultaneously and send it to a computer.

So, to do this I need `SSH` to every router. and I need a switch to `SSH` to  routers.
Here is an example setup:
[see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hszwf.png)

I will be able to start capturing packets and change wireless frequencies simultaneously with `SSH` connection with every router.

But `SSH` requires an IP address.
As far as I know unmanaged switches does not have a DHCP server.
So these routers will not be assigned to an IP address.

So the question is:
Can I `SSH` to routers connected with an unmanaged switch from a computer which connected to the same switch, or do I need a managed switch?

Comment: If you don't have a DHCP server you can manually assigned addresses to a router.  Most routers by default have their own DHCP service enabled.  You would want to disable that if you don't intend to use it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed vs unmanaged doesn't matter. It is usually not the job of a *switch,* in general, to serve DHCP. There are *some* switches which do serve DHCP, but the vast majority of even managed switches do not.

Instead, this is usually the job of either a router or a dedicated server. If the network doesn't have a router which could do it, then a DHCP server could be run on your own PC – several are available for Linux (e.g. dnsmasq, isc-dhcpd, kea), macOS (e.g. bootpd), and even for Windows.

Comment: I think I can do it with isc-dhcp-server. Thanks for your answer!